# How to slice a list containing a set of strings by comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of strings inside a list that I read from a CSV file and it looks like this:

```
myList = ('17.0.1.34', '17.1.182.21', '714'),('203.84.210.248', '27.111.228.3', '10310'),('202.73.40.45', '27.111.228.6', '18106'),...
```

I want to store it into a database (Django) that has three fields:

```
fieldOne = '17.0.1.34', '203.84.210.248','202.73.40.45', ....
fieldTwo = '17.1.182.21', '27.111.228.3', '27.111.228.6', ...
fieldThree = '714', '10310', '18106',...
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are `fieldOne`, `fieldTwo` etc. lists of strings or strings separated by a comma? If they're lists, please surround them with square brackets to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) your results and store them in a dictionary:

```
>>> myList = [('17.0.1.34', '17.1.182.21', '714'),('203.84.210.248', '27.111.228.3', '10310'),('202.73.40.45', '27.111.228.6', '18106')]
>>> fields = 'fieldOne', 'fieldTwo', 'fieldThree'
>>> dict(zip(fields, zip(*myList)))
{'fieldOne': ('17.0.1.34', '203.84.210.248', '202.73.40.45'), 'fieldTwo': ('17.1.182.21', '27.111.228.3', '27.111.228.6'), 'fieldThree': ('714', '10310', '18106')}
```

Then you can just reference the `'fieldOne'`, `'fieldTwo'`, `'fieldThree'` keys from this dictionary and store it in your database.

Answer (score 5):

You have a list of 3-tuples:

```
myList = [
    (a1, b1, c1),
    (a2, b2, c2),
    (a3, b3, c3),
    ...
]
```

You want to refactor this list into three variables:

```
fieldOne = [a1, a2, a3, ...]
fieldTwo = [b1, b2, b3, ...]
fieldThree = [c1, c2, c3, ...]
```

You can do this using list comprehension: "Make a list by taking the `k`th value from each element of `myList`". That would look like this:

```
fieldOne = [i[0] for i in myList]    # k = 0
fieldTwo = [i[1] for i in myList]    # k = 1
fieldThree = [i[2] for i in myList]  # k = 2
```

Of course, if your tuples are of variable length this gets much more complicated - but these are the fundamentals, and you can play around with them as needed to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given your data, here is a possible solution:

```
# Initialize each field list
fieldOne = []
fieldTwo = []
fieldThree = []

# fetch each **item** in **myList**, we extract the component corresponding
# append it to the appropriate field
for item in myList:
    fieldOne.append(item[0])
    fieldTwo.append(item[1])
    fieldThree.append(item[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the following way so you can use it multiple times.

```
def create_field(myList):
    fieldOne = [myList[i][0] for i in range(len(myList))]
    fieldTwo = [myList[i][1] for i in range(len(myList))]
    fieldThree = [myList[i][2] for i in range(len(myList))]
    return fieldOne, fieldTwo, fieldThree
create_field(myList)
```